# How do I add a boss bar linked to a player's health while other people being able to see it?

Tags: minecraft

I have a multiplayer server, basically, I want to make it so that a player IS the boss in this event. I want to make it so that there's a boss bar linked to said player's health and is visible to other players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be accomplished by creating a plugin using the Spigot API.

1. Create a [BossBar](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/boss/BossBar.html)
2. Add all players who should see it to the BossBar
3. Listen to the [EntityDamageEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDamageEvent.html), check if the entity damaged was the target player, and update the title to display the players new health